# How to process large Titan Graph using Spark

Tags: graph, apache-spark, cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I have loaded very large graph in TItan 1.0.0 with backend Cassandra 2.1.13. I have to perform some operations on the graphs using Spark.

For example,

1. I want to find subgraphs in a very large graph using Apache Spark
2. I want to run some clustering (machine learning code) on graph stored in Titan,etc.

Basically, I will be applying some algorithm on TitanGraph using Spark (which I suppose will be faster on a big graph)

I am able to find the any docs relating this, how to process the graph. Is the Spark a right approach to apply algorithms(Machine learning) on large graph? What should be my next steps?
How do I run my Spark code on Titan? (I am not able to find the exact methods or function through which I should be inserting/using Spark code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [SparkGraphComputer](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#sparkgraphcomputer)? This helps you apply Gremlin queries that will be executed on Spark framework. Have a look at this example:

```
gremlin> graph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop/hadoop-gryo.properties')
==>hadoopgraph[gryoinputformat->gryooutputformat]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(computer(SparkGraphComputer))
==>graphtraversalsource[hadoopgraph[gryoinputformat->gryooutputformat], sparkgraphcomputer]
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.hadoop graph g
==>useTraversalSource=graphtraversalsource[hadoopgraph[gryoinputformat->gryooutputformat], sparkgraphcomputer]
==>useSugar=false
gremlin> :> g.V().group().by{it.value('name')[1]}.by('name')
==>[a:[marko, vadas], e:[peter], i:[ripple], o:[josh, lop]]
```

Another way to go is to use the [GraphComputer](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#graphcomputer). This helps you a lot on applying OLAP and OLTP on the graph using Spark/Hadoop. Here is an example

```
gremlin> result = graph.compute().program(PageRankVertexProgram.build().create()).submit().get()
==>result[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:0],memory[size:0]]
gremlin> result.memory().runtime
==>95
gremlin> g = result.graph().traversal(standard())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap('name',PageRankVertexProgram.PAGE_RANK)
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.15000000000000002], name:[marko]]
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.19250000000000003], name:[vadas]]
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.4018125], name:[lop]]
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.19250000000000003], name:[josh]]
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.23181250000000003], name:[ripple]]
==>[gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:[0.15000000000000002], name:[peter]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [mizo](https://github.com/imri/mizo) for OLAP of Titan using spark -- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121262/reading-a-large-graph-from-titan-on-hbase-into-spark?rq=1) might be helpful.